# Blueimp File Upload angularjs json prefix

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, spring, blueimp

I'm using blueimp file upload angularjs version and have mostly got it working. The only area I'm having an issue with is parsing of the json response.

As recommended by angularjs team here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - all server responses of type application/json are prefixed with ")]}',\n" and angularjs is smart enough to strip it.

I'm wondering where in blueimp I can intercept/pre-process the response to strip the prefix as it isn't happening by default and causes a json parse error.

I have a spring mvc app with MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter class handling the response for all application/json types and cannot disable for specific requests as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same issue, I resolved this by adding a response header called "NoJsonPrefix" in my Spring MVC file upload controller class method. I then extend Spring MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter and check for a response header of NoJsonPrefix. If present, the json response is not prefixed. This works fine for the odd case where the json response should not be prefixed.

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("NoJsonPrefix", "true");
return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(generateResponse(documentDto), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

public class PrefixedMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter {

@Value("${http.response.json.prefix}")
private boolean prefixJson;

@Override
protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    JsonEncoding encoding = getJsonEncoding(outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
    JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = getObjectMapper().getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(outputMessage.getBody(), encoding);

    if (getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().isEnabled(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT)) {
        jsonGenerator.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    }

    String noJsonPrefix = outputMessage.getHeaders().getFirst("NoJsonPrefix");
    try {
        if (this.prefixJson && noJsonPrefix == null) {
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw(")]}',\n");
        }
        getObjectMapper().writeValue(jsonGenerator, object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
        throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

}

```
<mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="com.***.web.security.PrefixedMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="prefixJson" value="${http.response.json.prefix}" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```